# cpanm, perlbrew not working with sudo

Tags: perl, sudo, centos6, perlbrew, cpanm

I'm using CentOS 6.6 and install Perl, `cpanm`, and Perlbrew to it. But when I try to run Perlbrew (to install specific Perl version) or `cpanm` with sudoer permission, a "not found error" comes out:

```
sudo: cpanm: command not found
sudo: perlbrew: command not found
```

It's OK when running without sudoers permission or root permission. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the --sudo option for cpanm

cpanm --sudo some::package

or run sudo with -E to preserve environment, and pass PATH

```
sudo -E PATH="$PATH" cpanm some::package
```

This works if you have a perlbrew-ed Perl

Answer (score -1):

Possible duplicate of *[Command mvn and error message “command not found” when using sudo](https://superuser.com/questions/709515/command-not-found-when-using-sudo)* (cross-site).

sudo does not invoke a login shell, so it doesn't install any of your (modified) PATH's. Add the path of `rakudobrew/bin` to the `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers`.